# Beautiful soup 4: Extract text with no tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
<li class="actualPrice price fakeLink " data-automation="actual-price">
       <span class="visuallyhidden">Hello world</span>
Some text I want to extract
</li>
```

Here are some HTML.
I want to extract the text "Some text I want to extract", and I don't want to extract Hello world.

I have try something like find('span') and use next_sibling but I got None.

```
for a in soup.find_all('li', 'actualPrice'):
        print a.get_text()
```

And this give me Hello world and "Some text I want to extract".
Is there any methods that extract "Some text I want to extract" only?

Comment: `a.span.next.next` will give you `Some text I want to extract`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract next element after `span` tag then you can use `.next` :

```
>>> for a in soup.find_all('li', 'actualPrice'):
        print(a.span.next.next)
Some text I want to extract
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of another method you can use `stripped_strings`:

```
for li in soup.find_all('li', 'actualPrice'):
    _, text_you_want = li.stripped_strings
    print (text_you_want)
```

Outputs:

> Some text I want to extract